# linux match pattern after a line number till end and replace once

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

The requirement is like this:

Input file:

```
.......
.......
foo ......
.......
.......
foo ......
.......
.......
foo ......
.......
.......
```

Output File:

```
.......
.......
foo bar
.......
.......
foo nobar
.......
.......
foo barno
.......
.......
```

I've thought of the logic and found parts to implement the above. This is how the logic goes.

1. Initially `lineno=0`
2. Match pattern starting from `lineno` till end of file. Once pattern is found, get the line number, `lineno=<matched line number> + 1`, replace only once with 1st value.
3. repeat the 2nd step with 2nd value.
4. repeat the 2nd step with 3rd value.

I've only found, how to get the line number of matched pattern, how to replace only once. But for the first part "start matching from a specific line number of the file", I'm not getting anything.

Can the above requirement be possible in linux?

Mentioned logic is preferable as it can be handled in a loop. Other ideas/ improvisions are also welcome.

**Edit 1:**

After all the comments, this is my 1st try:

```
x=($(awk '/foo/ {print NR}' foo_test))    #foo_test contains the above input
sed -i "${x[0]}s/.*/foo bar/" foo_test
sed -i "${x[1]}s/.*/foo nobar/" foo_test
sed -i "${x[2]}s/.*/foo barno/" foo_test
```

Is there any other better solution?

Comment: You're doing this as a learning exercise? If not, and this is a simplification of a work problem, then sample data that is a little closer to your problem would be helpful above. In any case, the `awk` language is very well designed for such problems. Work your way thru the [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and you'll be close. Then read as many of @EdMorton 's posts here as you can. Your 1st line of awk code would be `awk '/^foo/{lineno=NR;print "#dbg: matched foo at "lineno}' file` All `awk` vars are initialed as zero, so you don't need to set them explicitly. Good luck.

Comment: yes the above requirement is possible in linux, especially in awk. Missing your attempt in solving this problem.

Comment: @shellter That is the exact sample data. I'll have a look at awk. Thanks.

Comment: @DudiBoy I was trying with `sed`. Couldn't implement the 1st part. So didn't give my attempt. I'll try with awk.

Comment: @DudiBoy Added my attempt. :D

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample awk script to do the task in one sweep.

input file `input.txt`:

```
line 1
foo line 2
foo line 3
line 4
foo line 5
foo line 6
line 7
line 8
foo line 9
foo line 10
line 11
foo line 12
```

awk script `script.awk`:

```
/^foo / {               # for each input line starting with foo
    fooCount++;         # increment foo coutner
    if (fooCount%3 == 1) $1 = $1" bar";   # First match. Add bar to 1st field
    if (fooCount%3 == 2) $1 = $1" nobar"; # Second match. Add nobar to 1stfield
    if (fooCount%3 == 0) $1 = $1" barno"; # Third match. Add barno to 1st field
}
1                       # print current line
```

run command:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

output:

```
line 1
foo bar line 2
foo nobar line 3
line 4
foo barno line 5
foo bar line 6
line 7
line 8
foo nobar line 9
foo barno line 10
line 11
foo bar line 12
```

Please comment